How to handle FileCdnRedirect in Telethon when downloading files?
I'm using the Telethon library in Python to download files from Telegram, but I'm encountering an issue where a FileCdnRedirect exception is raised during the download process.
The relevant code snippet is:
if isinstance(result, types.upload.FileCdnRedirect):
    if self.client._mb_entity_cache.self_bot:
        raise ValueError('FileCdnRedirect but the GetCdnFileRequest API access for bot users is restricted. Try to change api_id to avoid FileCdnRedirect')
    raise _CdnRedirect(result)


The exception raised looks like this:
telethon.client.downloads._CdnRedirect: FileCdnRedirect(dc_id=203, file_token=b'...', encryption_key=b'...', encryption_iv=b'...', file_hashes=[...])


My Questions:

Why does Telegram sometimes redirect file downloads to a CDN,
causing this exception in Telethon?
How should I properly handle this FileCdnRedirect to successfully
download and decrypt the file?
Is there a way to avoid CDN redirection altogether, or is it
something that must be handled by the client? Any guidance or
examples on handling this scenario within Telethon would be greatly
appreciated!

